# No extension protocol but still works

Tags: swift

When following twostraws' tutorial, I create an extension of Int, but then I apply the extension method on UInt64, it stills work. Can someone tell me why? The original tutorial is here. [Protocol extension](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/0/24/protocol-extensions)

```swift
extension Int{
    func clamp(high: Int, low: Int)->Int{
        if self > high {
            return high
        }
        else if self < low{
            return low
        }
        return self
    }
}

let bigNum: UInt64 = 5
5.clamp(high: 10, low: 0)
```

Comment: Did you mean `bigNum.clamp(high: 10, low: 0)` to really test? Does it work then?

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling `UInt64` here, to do it you will have to write it as so:

```swift
bigNum.clamp(high: 10, low: 0)
```

which should produce compiler error.

When calling `5.clamp(...)` you actually instantiate new `Int` because `5` without any context is an [Integer Literal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyintegerliteral)